On insert mode letting backspace to work, with but
How, in Lua setting file, do we have Neovim insert mode letting backspace to work wherever cursor is not at start of line, but then at the start of line it must by default to do nothing, as it was.
That is: Default to do nothing at the start of line.

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

This behavior is controlled by the backspace option and more specifically by the presence of start in that list of values.
To have the backspace key not deleting the previous carriage return do:
In Lua:
vim.opt.backspace:remove("start")

in VimScript:
set backspace-=start

Remark:

The default value for this option is indent,eol,start in Neovim (this let the backspace key delete indentation, start of line and delete delete the end of the line)
The default value for this option is '' in Vim

More information with:

:help 'backspace' for Neovim
:help 'backspace' for Vim

